# How to extract coefficients from ButterworthFilterModel

Tags: recursion, filtering

I have created a 3rd order Butterworth lowpass filter, and from that, a discrete version.

```
rate = 120.;
dt = 1/rate;
corner = 12;
tf = ButterworthFilterModel[{3, corner 2 Pi}];
tfd = ToDiscreteTimeModel[tf, dt];
```

I would like to transform tdf into the coefficients of the recurrence equation, so that I can implement my own recursive filter as a set of gains and delays.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get numerical values, you will need to set rate to something, I set it to 1. If you look at the internal structure of tdf, you will see that the numerator polynomial is contained in

```
num=tfd[[1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

and the denominator polynomial is in

```
den=tfd[[1, 2, 1, 1]]
```

Then you can get the list of coefficients from these using:

```
cnum = CoefficientList[Expand[num], \[FormalZ] ]
{428631., 1.28589*10^6, 1.28589*10^6, 428631.}

dnum = CoefficientList[Chop[Expand[den // N]], \[FormalZ] ]
{406486., 1.26257*10^6, 1.308*10^6, 451982.}
```

These will be the coefficients of the filter which you can implement using RecurrenceFilter, for instance:

```
RecurrenceFilter[{Reverse[cden], Reverse[cnum]}, in]
```

where `in` is the input to the filter.

Alternatively, if you prefer to implement the filyter in state space form, you can find the value of the a,b,c matrices using:

```
Normal[StateSpaceModel[tfd]] // N
```

Comment: Thanks! I did actually set a rate=120. However, when I then attempt:cnum = CoefficientList[Expand[num], \[FormalZ]]
cden = CoefficientList[Chop[Expand[den // N]], \[FormalZ]]
in = Join[{1}, ConstantArray[0, n - 1]];
out = RecurrenceFilter[{cden, cnum}, in]; I get something that does not look correct.

Comment: Well -- look at cnum and look at cden and see if they make sense. Saying only that "it does not look correct" is not particularly helpful.

Comment: num = tfd[[1, 1, 1, 1]];
den = tfd[[1, 2, 1, 1]];
cnum = CoefficientList[Expand[num], \[FormalZ]];
cden = CoefficientList[Chop[Expand[den // N]], \[FormalZ]];
n = 120;
in = Join[{1}, ConstantArray[0, n - 1]];
out1 = RecurrenceFilter[tfd, in];
out2 = RecurrenceFilter[{cden, cnum}, in]; The two results are completely different. Not sure how to show a plot or output in a comment.

Comment: If you look at cnum and cden, then you will see *why* your answers do not align. Coefficient list is pulling the coefficients out from the tfd in the opposite order from that which you seem to expect. In other words: use `RecurrenceFilter[{Reverse[cden], Reverse[cnum]}, in]`

Comment: Aha! I actually had this thought as I was waking this morning. Clearly just a good nights sleep was required.